# Revit Python Wrapper

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell

i'm getting into revit python wrapper / revit python shell and am having trouble on a very simple task.

I have one wall in my project and I'm just trying to change the top offset from 0'- 0" to 4'-0". I've been able to change the Comments in the properties but that's about it.

Here's my code:

```
import rpw
from rpw import revit, db, ui, DB, UI

element = db.Element.from_int(352690)
with db.Transaction('Change height'):
    element.parameters['Top Offset'].value = 10
```

Here's my error:

```
[ERROR] Error in Transaction Context: has rolled back.
Exception : System.Exception: Parameter is Read Only: Top Offset
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.HandleException(InterpretedFrame frame, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.ExecuteAndWrap(ScriptScope scope, ObjectHandle& exception)
```

Any and all help is appreciated. I've read the docs however they dont seem to go over Read Only items.

I'm in revit 2019. RPS is using python 2.7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a "Revit Python Wrapper" (RPW) question more than a "RevitPythonShell" (RPS) one, Im familiar with the way transactions are handled in RPS but the documentation for RPW seems quite different.

This is what your code would look like in RevitPythonShell:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI') 
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI') 
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import * 
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import *
app = __revit__.Application
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
ui = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument

element = doc.GetElement(ElementId(352690))

t = Transaction (doc, 'Change Height')
t.Start()
parameter = element.GetParameters('Top Offset')[0]
parameter.Set(10)   
t.Commit()
```

Comment: That did it. thanks! Another thing to note that I found out is that the wall has to have the TOP CONSTRAINT set to a level. It cannot be set to "unconnected". That may have been my mistake.